# How do you get the item's index with i, v in pairs

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a game, and I am trying to random an item in the table, so I used i,v in pairs, but It only gives me the name of the item, how do I get the item? It is a function. Can anyone knows the answer and tell me, thank you.

The code I scripted down there

```
for i,v in pairs(TTH) do -- Making the for loop
    TTH.     -- Didn't know what to do
end -- Ending of for loop
```

I scripted it and searched up there and finds nothing, a table can't use FindFirstChild so can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: The usual approach to choosing a random item out of a set of items with a uniform distribution is to first put the items in a list, then choose an item using `items[math.random(1, #items)]`.

Comment: The item is stored in `v`.

Answer (score 1):

Lua for loops are implemented in this way:

```lua
for i, v in pairs(table) do
  -- i: index
  -- v: value
end
```

If you were doing a for loop, you'd be iterating over each instance inside `TTH` (TTH would have to be a table) which is not the intended behavior.

Let's say you had a folder named TTH and wanted to get a random child in that folder each time the script was executed. You would want to do:

```lua
local childTable = TTH:GetChildren()
local child = items[math.random(1, #children)]
```

Comment: In yours example `i` is not index, is a key. If you want to have only indexed values from 1 to first `nil` you have to use `ipairs` instead `pairs`.

Comment: But my table is required from a module script.